# Chrome extension: load external page in iframe and read innerHTML

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I've found a few examples and pieced together an extension. But I never managed to get it to work. It's always some error showing up and now I've given up.

Can someone give me a full fledged example on how to do this (if it's even possible).

The reason why I wanna load an iframe is because if I use XMLHttpRequest to read the page I won't get the HTML that is generated with Javascript.

See code below.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Example ...",
  "description": "Will let you get browser notifications from ...",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src http://example.com 'self' ; object-src 'self'",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://example.com/*",
    "notifications",
    "cookies",
  ],
    "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  }
}
```

background.html:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://www.example.com/"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried creating the iframe via JavaScript instead but that makes no difference.

Comment: What is `XmlHttpConnection`?

Comment: Writing an answer containg a full extension would be doing quite a lot of dirty work. I have a lot of exepreince in doing these kind of things so if you post some code you have that's not working I'll be glad to point out the solution.

Comment: I meant XMLHttpRequest (edited). @orcaman I will update my question with some code. Sorry if it's a lot of work, the examples I've seen hasn't been that code heavy., therefore I thought someone had a simple solution

Answer (score -1):

Wait for the iframe to load and then grab it's content with jQuery:

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
   $(this).contents().find('html').html();
});
```

Comment: Won't work cross-domain (and it's guaranteed to be cross-domain)

Comment: @Xan it runs from a Chrome extension, it can definitely work cross domain (you control the response headers and you can allow it).

Comment: No, while you can send requests cross-domain that does not exempt you from normal web security when the page is loaded. Chrome will deny reading `.contents()`.